# "on a simplistic level" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can anybody help me with meaning of "on a simplistic level", for example in:

> People travel more. What are the causes?
>
> The reasons are many and varied. **On a simplistic level**, there are a larger number of means of transportation. However this is not enough to explain this increase.
>
> On a simplistic level, one may be inclined to ask: "Why not?"

I could not find any definition in the Internet.

Comment: It is synonymous with "on the surface" and "at first glance". Can you work out its meaning now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplistic means more than just 'simple'; it means that what it's describing is *overly* simple, that the actual situation is complex and difficult but it's being treated as though it has a single obvious answer.

In this context, 'level' refers to how deeply you are looking at the situation. You can consider only the most obvious elements that can be observed with a brief examination, or you can focus on the complex subtleties and realize that you missed a lot in that first look.

So the phrase "on a simplistic level" means "looking at only the obvious elements of the situation, ignoring any complicating factors".